# Factory Pattern implementation without reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, factory-pattern

I am doing some research on design pattern implementation variants, i have come across and read some examples implemented here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37547/Exploring-Factory-Pattern and http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html. My focus of concern is when implementing factory pattern without reflection . the stated articles said that we need to register objects not classes which seems fine and logical to me but when seeing the implementation i see the duplication of objects e.g in the code below

```
// Factory pattern method to create the product
public IRoomType CreateProduct(RoomTypes Roomtype)
{
    IRoomType room = null;
    if (registeredProducts.Contains(Roomtype))
    {
        room = (IRoomType)registeredProducts[Roomtype];
        room.createProduct();
    }
    if (room == null) { return room; }
    else { return null; }
}

// implementation of concrete product
class NonACRoom : IRoomType
{
    public static void RegisterProduct()
    {
        RoomFactory.Instance().RegisterProduct(new NonACRoom(), RoomTypes.NonAcRoom);
    }
    public void getDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am an NON AC Room");
    }
    public IRoomType createProduct()
    {
        return new NonACRoom();
    }
}
```

the method RegisterProduct is used for self registeration, we have to call it anyways before creating factory object i.e before some where in the main class of the client or anywhere applicable that ensure its calling. below is we are creating a new product and in the method above we are creating again a new product which seems non sense. any body comment on that

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar to this in the past.  This is essentially what I came up with (and also doing away with the whole "Type" enumeration):

```
public interface ICreator
{
    IPart Create();
}


public interface IPart
{
    // Part interface methods
}


// a sample creator/part

public PositionPartCreator : ICreator
{
    public IPart Create() { return new PositionPart(); }
}

public PositionPart : IPart
{
    // implementation
}
```

Now we have the factory itself:

```
public sealed class PartFactory
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IPartCreator> creators_ = new Dictionary<Type, IPartCreator>();

    // registration (note, we use the type system!)
    public void RegisterCreator<T>(IPartCreator creator) where T : IPart
    {
        creators_[typeof(T)] = creator;
    }


    public T CreatePart<T>() where T: IPart
    {
        if(creators_.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
            return creators_[typeof(T)].Create();
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

This essentially does away with the need for a "type" enumeration, and makes things really easy to work with:

```
PartFactory factory = new PartFactory();
factory.RegisterCreator<PositionPart>(new PositionPartCreator());
// all your other registrations



// ... later


IPart p = factory.CreatePart<PositionPart>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first creation is used to give something to work on to `RegisterProduct`. Probably, the cost of that object is neglectable. It's done during initialization and won't matter much.

This instance is required though because in C# you need an object to call `createProduct` on. This is because you can't use reflection to store a reference to a type instead of a reference to an object.

Comment: i am sorry i couldnt got you much. can you please elaborate. I see 2 objects created for a same thing, if we have a hash map and we have that object registered why should we reuse it instead of creating it

Comment: Because the factory pattern is meant to create **NEW** objects. In a factory pattern, the ultimate goal is to create many objects. In that special case, you need a first instance and then you use that first one to create many new ones. `createProduct` is usually called thousands of a time in such an application.

Comment: the biggest disadvantage of self registeration with reflection and without reflection is the loading of classes before the method call which couple the client and factory classes.

Comment: Brother, i am still scratching my head on this sentence, can you provide some help specially this phrase "This is because you can't use reflection to store a reference to a type instead of a reference to an object"

Comment: If you were to use reflection, you would do something like `Factory::Register(typeof(NonACRoom))` and manipulate the `System.Type` object to create instances (using `Activator` for instance). Without reflection, the only thing you can manipulate is an instance of `IRoomType` so you need to create one of each. I hope this helps :/